# Automapper use ProjectTo after GroupBy

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core, automapper

Here are the Entity and the ViewModel:

```cs
public class Journal
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public string SKU { get; set; }
    public int Count { get; set; }

    public virtual Product Product { get; set; }
}
```

```cs
public class AnalysisVM
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public JObject SKU { get; set; }
    public int Count { get; set; }
}
```

I want use AutoMapper ProjectTo after GroupBy like this.

```cs
var results = await _context.Journals.Where(x => x.Date <= date)
                                     .GroupBy(x => new { x.ProductId, x.SKU })
                                     .ProjectTo<AnalysisVM>(_mapper.ConfigurationProvider)
                                     .ToListAsync();
```

According this [LINQ GroupBy Aggregation with AutoMapper](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46876543/5954068),

I Create Mapper Profile

```cs
CreateMap<string, JObject>().ConvertUsing(s => JObject.Parse(s));

CreateMap<IEnumerable<Journal>, AnalysisVM>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.ProductId, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.FirstOrDefault().ProductId))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.SKU, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.FirstOrDefault().SKU))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Count, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Sum(x => x.Count)));
```

But thing goes wrong. How to use ProjectTo to GroupBy?

```
[2024-03-04 16:59:36 DBG 47] <Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query> Compiling query expression: 
'DbSet<Journal>()
    .Where(x => x.Date <= __date_0)
    .GroupBy(x => new { 
        ProductId = x.ProductId, 
        SKU = x.SKU
     })
    .Select(dtoIGrouping`2 => new Object_7062817___SKU{ __SKU = dtoIGrouping`2.FirstOrDefault().SKU }
    )
    .Select(dtoLet => new AnalysisVM{ 
        ProductId = dtoIGrouping`2.FirstOrDefault().ProductId, 
        SKU = JObject.Parse(dtoLet.__SKU), 
        Count = dtoIGrouping`2.Sum(x => x.Count)
    }
    )' 

[2024-03-04 16:59:36 ERR 47] <Web.Infrastructure.Filters.HttpGlobalExceptionFilter> The LINQ expression 'dtoIGrouping`2' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.
```

Package Version

"AutoMapper" Version="12.0.1"

"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="6.0.13"

"Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql" Version="6.0.2"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Client side GroupBy is not supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58138556/client-side-groupby-is-not-supported)

Comment: This error is not related to AutoMapper, but to the inability of EF to translate GroupBy to a server-side query. You'll need to do the projection first, so the GroupBy can be evaluated client-side.

Comment: TBH was not able to reproduce. Works for me just fine in my repro code. Can you please provide a [mre]?

Comment: What EF Core version are you using? What database provider? What AutoMapper version?

Comment: in this scenario, I think the groupBy is not client side.@janw

Comment: It is case when Automapper is useless. Project analytic queries by hands. As I see even configuration is ineffective and wrong. It should be `CreateMap<IGrouping< AnonymousType, Journal>>` - you have to specify grouping key as non anonymous class. DO NOT use Automapper everywhere, use common sense.

Comment: @GuruStron  In error log, I notice `SKU` be selected twice. It may be because of the SKU type. If change the type  of  `AnalysisVM.SKU`  to `String`. It works. But I don't understand the reason:(

Comment: @qslcna for me using `JObject` directly resulted in Automapper error (I have added manual `JObject.Parse` manually to mapping). Please share [mre].

Comment: @janw actually it is automapper issues or more precise automapper configuration issue (at least based on my tests).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "automatic" mapping of `JObject` is the issue:

```
CreateMap<string, JObject>().ConvertUsing(s => JObject.Parse(s));
```

Try inlining it (worked for me with latest EF Core and AutoMapper):

```
CreateMap<IEnumerable<Journal>, AnalysisVM>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.SKU, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => JObject.Parse(src.FirstOrDefault().SKU)))
    // ... 
    ;
```

Personally I would just use "manual" projection here which also will allow using grouping key to potentially allowing EF to generate better SQL (though you can set up it with AutoMapper also, but then you will need to create a type for the grouping key):

```
var results = await _context.Journals.Where(x => x.Date <= date)
    .GroupBy(x => new { x.ProductId, x.SKU })
    .Select(g => new AnalysisVM
    {
        ProductId = g.Key.ProductId,
        // .. 
    })
    .ToListAsync();
```